# to discuss intelligence

Tags: meaning-in-context

“We understand the tyranny of time here,” a senior U.S. defense official told reporters, speaking on the condition of anonymity ***to discuss intelligence and other sensitive matters***.

[Reference](https://www.voanews.com/a/biden-announces-new-assistance-after-zelenskyy-asks-for-more-us-help/6488192.html)

---

I'm not sure what the role of "***to***" is, and what "***to discuss intelligence and other sensitive matters***" modifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**to** means "for the purpose of", just like in "Read this book *to* learn more."

**intelligence** has [meaning 2b here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intelligence):

> 2 b : information concerning an enemy or possible enemy or an area

The whole phrase means that the official spoke anonymously so that they could talk about information concerning an enemy and other similar topics.